# MongoDB: "Unknown top level operator 'nameOnly' " error from Java, but everything is ok from Mongo Shell

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

We have an interesting problem.

We have a java application (Java 8, Spring boot, MongoDB driver 3.8.2) with a simple MongoDB GUI tool.

**Case 1.** My dev local machine. MongoDB 3.6.0. Non-admin user.

Part of the java-code:

```
mongoClient.listDatabaseNames()
```

returns list of the available database names.

Everything is fine.

**Case 2.** Remote server.  MongoDB 3.6.0. Non-admin user.

The same application, the same line:

```
mongoClient.listDatabaseNames()
```

throws an error:

```
"Command failed with error 2: 'unknown top level operator 'nameOnly' on server ... ' "
```

We tried to run the same using mongo shell (to check 'nameOnly' operator):

```
use admin
db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true } )
```

Output:

```
{
     "databases" : [
                {
                  "name" : "db1"
                },

      ---other databases---
                   ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Mongo Java Driver logs (from ServerMonitor.java):

Localhost (from case 1):

```
Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description 

ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=203835}
```

Remote (from case 2):

```
Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description 

ServerDescription{address=host:ip, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777208, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=5633088, setName='rs0', canonicalAddress=host:ip, hosts=[host:ip,host:ip], passives=[], arbiters=[host:ip], primary='host:ip', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=somedata, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=null, lastUpdateTimeNanos=8767847038926801}
```

Any ideas? Is it related to "REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY"  type? Thanks.

P.S. I replaced some private data with host:ip, I hope it's clear.